# nginx - exclude all but two files

Tags: nginx

I need to allow the internet access to 2 files on my Nginx 1.6.0 web server:

[www.example.com/piwik.php][1]

[www.example.com/piwik.js][2]

Everything else needs to be blocked.  What is the correct location directive to use?  I have the below and it is only partially working:

```
# allow everyone to access piwik.php
location ~ /piwik.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}

# allow everyone to access piwik.js
location ~ /piwik.js$ {
  root html;
  index index.html index.htm;
}

# The below appears to allow index.php to load, but blocks
# files beneath it (e.g. js/file1.js, imgs/pic1.jpg) so the page 
# is only half-rendered and I see a bunch of 403's in my NGINX logs.
# People are still able to access the half-loaded index.php webform 
# and login!!!

location / {            
    allow 192.168.1.1
    deny all;
    root   html;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
}
```

Access Log below:

```
1.2.3.4 - - [04/May/2014:20:04:22 -0400] "GET 
/libs/jquery/stylesheets/jquery.smartbanner.css?cb=ef21e462d0300ea546811bec0ee6a912 
HTTP/1.1" 403 162 "https://example.com/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 
7_1_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11D201 
Safari/9537.53"

1.2.3.4 - - [04/May/2014:20:04:22 -0400] "GET /plugins/Login/stylesheets/login.css?
cb=ef21e462d0300ea546811bec0ee6a912 HTTP/1.1" 403 162 "https://example.com/index.php" 
"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_1_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.2 (KHTML, 
like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11D201 Safari/9537.53"

1.2.3.4 - - [04/May/2014:20:03:15 -0400] "GET /plugins/Morpheus/images/logo.svg 
HTTP/1.1" 403 162 "https://example.com/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 
7_1_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11D201 
Safari/9537.53"
```

The errors look like the below when users try to access the main page (`index.php`).

```
2014/05/06 14:17:51 [error] 6917#0: *385 access forbidden by rule, client: 180.76.X.X, server: example.com, request: "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com"

2014/05/06 15:21:47 [error] 6917#0: *392 access forbidden by rule, client: 66.249.X.X, server: example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com"

2014/05/06 15:38:24 [error] 6917#0: *398 access forbidden by rule, client: 66.249.X.X, server: example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com"

2014/05/06 19:02:45 [error] 6917#0: *412 access forbidden by rule, client: 66.249.X.X, server: example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com"

2014/05/06 20:06:04 [error] 6917#0: *413 access forbidden by rule, client: 185.4.X.X, server: example.com, request: "GET http://24x7-allrequestsallowed.com/?PHPSESSID=1rmsxtj500143PRTJWQAY%40D%5EJFSX HTTP/1.1", host: "24x7-allrequestsallowed.com"

2014/05/06 20:09:22 [error] 6917#0: *414 access forbidden by rule, client: 66.249.X.X, server: example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com"
```

Comment: could you include a chunk of your error.log?

Comment: I have added the 403 message I see in my web access.

Comment: thats your access.log, need to see the actual error messages in the  error.log

Comment: Added some error.log messages from the Nginx error log.

Comment: according to those errors, its working as it should - hosts not in 192.168.1.1 are denied...so you're saying that with that specifc error, users are still receiving part of the index.php? Even if they do a full `shift-F5` (full reload) of the page? That certainly would be a bug if thats the case...

Comment: "... so you're saying that with that specifc error, users are still receiving part of the index.php?" If I go to example.com from a different IP address other than 192.168.1.1, then I get a 403 forbidden.  But if I go to example.com/index.php, then I get a partial load of the web page and can see the web input forms and can submit data.  This is even after doing a hard refresh (shift+F5). Do you think there is something else in my Nginx configuration that is set up incorrectly?

Comment: if i'm reading correctly (50/50) from a -different- IP address, example.com/index.php will partial load, but example.com will 403? Unless there is more to your config, that shouldn't happen, that deny should drop all...does php process the page when its a partial-load?